# Matriz como passagem de parâmetro em C

Tags: c, submenu

Olá, minha duvida é o seguinte, gostaria de saber como faço no código abaixo, para que minha matriz seja lida dentro do main, e após dentro do subprograma, um vetor receba os valores desta matriz e e exiba a matriz lida?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define tam 4


void exibirresultado(int provNot[][3]);

int main(){
     int provNot [tam][3];
     int i,j;

     printf("\n #########################################\n");

            for(i=1; i<=tam; i++){
            printf("Digite a nota do  %d aluno:\n",i);
                for(j=0; j<3; j++){
                    printf("Prova %d :\n",j+1);
                    scanf("%d",&provNot[i][j]); 
            }
        }
            exibirresultado(provNot);

    }   
    void exibirresultado(int provNot[][3]){
        int i,j,teste[tam][3];
                for(i=1; i<=tam; i++){
                    for(j=0;i<3;j++){
                        teste[i][j]=provNot[i][j];
                    }
                }
                    for(i=1; i<=tam; i++){
                    for(j=0;i<3;j++){
                        printf("%d === %d",i, teste[i][j]);
                    }
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite.
Para exibir o conteúdo contido nos endereços da matriz pode usar este código:

```
int matriz[LINHA][COLUNA] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}};
int i, j;
for(i = 0; i < LINHA; i++)
 for(j = 0; j < COLUNA; j++)
  printf("%d \n", matriz[i][j]);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Arrays são indexados em 0**, portanto as interações ficam:

```
for(i=0; i<tam; i++)
```

**O índice para as provas (`j`), para se iterar sobre elas, sempre fará comparação com o total de provas, não `i`**:

```
for(j=0; j<3; j++)
```

**Melhore seu código:**

Um `#define tam 4` não é muito intuitivo.
Busque usar nomes que se assemelham com o que guardam/contém:

```
#define TOTAL_PROFS 4
#define QUANT_PROVAS 3

int notas_alunos [TOTAL_PROFS][QUANT_PROVAS];
```

**Evite o uso de nome de variáveis como `i`**, sobretudo quando se está aprendendo, pois elas se confundem facilmente, e é necessário entender o que fazem ali.